# How to specify continuous color spectrum in a custom BarLegend?

Tags: color, legending

I want to create a custom [BarLegend](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html) with continuous colors:

```
Block[{minmax,ticks, cf},
    ticks = Function[{min, max},({#,StringForm["`` dBa",#]} )&  /@ Range[min,max]];
    minmax = {70,90};
    cf = ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][Rescale[#, minmax]] &;
    BarLegend[{cf, minmax}, "Ticks" -> ticks @@minmax]
]
```

Ticks are properly displayed. But the `BarLegend` is drawn using a solid color. What did I do wrong?

[image: Bar legend rendered with solid colors instead of a continuous spectrum]

Answer (score 3):

Moving the `minmax` constant out of the `Block` construct works:

```
With[{
        minmax = {70,90}
    },Block[{ticks, cf},
        ticks = Function[{min, max}, ({#,StringForm["`` dBa",#]} )&  /@ Range[min,max]];
        cf = ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][Rescale[#, minmax]] &;
        BarLegend[{cf, minmax}, "Ticks" -> ticks @@minmax]

    ]
]
```

[image]

I can't explain *why*, though.

Comment: If you look at the `InputForm` of your `BarLegend` you can see what's going wrong: The `minmax` inside `cf` is stored in its unevaluated form inside the legend expression. When the expression is finally displayed, it fails, as `minmax` is no longer set. (You can think of `BarLegend` and similar legend expressions as analogues to `Graphics` expressions - they don't evaluate on their own, they are simply typeset in a non-standard way, resulting in graphical output instead of the raw expressions.)

Comment: Thanks, Lukas. Actually, this is exactly what I did and how I had the idea to wrap the `Block` inside a `With`! Unfortunately, I didn't quite understand why `minmax` was not bound to the actual value. I didn't use Mathematica for a few weeks, and I think I've forgotten (again!) the difference of semantic between `Block` and `With`. :/